# Custom elements in Mule Flow

Tags: mule

I would like to add some custom elements to a mule flow, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:custom="http://www.example.com/schema/custom"
xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.example.com/schema/custom file:/example/schema/custom.xsd">

<flow name="myFlow">
    <custom:template name="generic-xml" type="flow"/>
    <custom:template name="file" type="message-source"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

Is it possible to do this? If yes, how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not intend to perform any processing using this custom elements. They are not supposed to call any Java method. I just want them to be there so that I can use the attributes inside the elements for getting some info in future.

Comment: Everything in Mule is a processor, don't be scared of the name.
If you need to extract data from the payload to be used later, you may need an enritcher.
If you actually need a custom processor that only observe the message, but actually don't transform it, you might want to implement an observer : http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Custom+Message+Processors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to create custom elements (message sources and processors) to a Mule configuration is to use the [DevKit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/DEVKIT/Home).

Don't get fooled by the *cloud connector* marketing lingo attached to DevKit: it will allow you to do way more than connecting to the cloud!

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the [MessageProcessor](http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/processor/MessageProcessor.html) interface and call it with [custom-processor or processor](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-CustomProcessor):

Or alternatively you could write your own module with [DevKit](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/DEVKIT/Creating+Message+Processors).

Comment: Ops! I just have a "race-condition" with David ;)